# Type casting fails even though I have implicit operators

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have written custom type with implicit cast operator

```
public class TcBool : TcDataTypeBase
{
    public TcBool() : base(1, false) { } //For somewhat reason without this callin new TcBool() fails
    public TcBool(bool value = false) : base(1, value) { }

    public static implicit operator bool(TcBool var) => (bool)var.Value;

    public static implicit operator TcBool(bool value) => new TcBool(value);
}

public abstract class TcDataTypeBase
{
    public readonly byte Size;
    public readonly object Value;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int IndexGroup { get; set; }
    public int IndexOffset { get; set; }

    internal TcDataTypeBase(byte size, object value)
    {
        Size = size;
        Value = value;
    }

    internal TcDataTypeBase(string name, byte size, object value) : this(size, value)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Then when I try to write it into a boolean property of an object using PropertyInfo.SetValue() it throws an exception saying it can't cast TcBool to System.Boolean.

Is there something preventing the reflection mechanisms from using the implicit conversion or am I missing something?

Comment: `new TcBool(value)` do you have a constructor for this?

Comment: Yes, I have a constructor that calls the base type constructor. It works fine in most scenarios. It's PropertyInfo.SetValue() case that gives me trouble. I've updated the code in post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know it has to cast anything, because SetValue accepts an `object`, which is type-compatible with `TcBool` without any cast (and indeed, you cannot define an implicit cast operator to an ancestor type). To force a cast, you can do this:

```
property.SetValue(instance, (bool)TcBool);
```

This will trigger your implicit cast operator and create a Boolean, which is then boxed into an object and passed to SetValue.

Comment: Explicit casting wouldn't work in my case, as I am working with multiple types, that have to be handled on the fly. But I've solved the problem simply by casting the variable to my base type first and then getting it's Value property: PropertyInfo.SetValue(ownerObject, 
 (TcDataTypeBase)variable).Value);

Answer (score 1):

Conversion operators have to be used by the compiler. Or rather, the compiler figures out that a conversion can be applied and inserts the appropriate call. At runtime this does not happen and you're left with incompatible types here, since `PropertyInfo.SetValue` just takes an `object`, so from the compiler's point of view no conversion is necessary.

Comment: Dang, you might be right, as I actually take value from function that returns it as System.Object. I'll check this.

Comment: `dynamic` won't help here.

Comment: @yaakov: Damn, now that I'm awake, you're absolutely right. Since there's no need for conversion at compile time or runtime there's no way `dynamic` will do anything here.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I realize that this is possibly overkill and will not work in case you don't know the types at compile time.

---

The important thing to know is that the **implicit conversion operators are compiled into methods called [`"op_Implicit"`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15191/Understanding-Implicit-Operator-Overloading-in-C)** and will therefore **not automatically be called**.

So I created this (rather long) and hacky helper method which converts an object of type `TObject` to an object of type `TTo` while taking into account implicit conversion operators:

```
public static object Convert<TObject, TTo>(TObject obj)
{
    IEnumerable<MethodInfo> implicitConversionOperators = obj.GetType()
                                                             .GetMethods()
                                                             .Where(mi => mi.Name == "op_Implicit");
    MethodInfo fittingImplicitConversionOperator = null;

    foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in implicitConversionOperators)
    {
        if (methodInfo.GetParameters().Any(parameter => parameter.ParameterType == typeof(TObject)))
        {
            fittingImplicitConversionOperator = methodInfo;
        }
    }

    if (fittingImplicitConversionOperator != null)
    {
        return fittingImplicitConversionOperator.Invoke(null, new object[] {obj});
    }

    return (TTo) System.Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(TTo));
}
```

Of course it is far from being perfect, but it can be used like this

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(this, Helper.Convert<TcBool, bool>(new TcBool(true)));
```

to set the property. Of course, if you don't know the types at compile time / don't want to have to be that verbose you could try `dynamic` etc. as it is shown in the other answers.

Comment: Yea, I can't be sure of type I'm going to be writing at compile time, but I know for sure it will inherit from my TcDataTypeBase, so I just cast the object into my base type and then I can get it's hidden value by property, so thanks for trying to help, but ultimately the solution resulted to be much simpler :)

Comment: @Nidrax When writing above code I already knew the solution would be simpler ;) but glad to hear that you solved it.